# Trying to "pick up" an item but it gives an error

Tags: java, 2d, game-development

I am currently following RyiSnow's tutorial for a 2D game in Java for my finals project. I do understand most of what is happening in the code since he explains it quite well.

The problem it that whenever I try to "pick up" a item, it should disappear as what the tutorial showcased. But when it I try to add this specific code to make it seem as the item has disappeared, the program encounters an error and would freeze.

```
if(i != 999) {
     gp.obj[i] = null;
}
```

The 999 is a value that's returned from a collisionChecker class to know whether the object and player were in a collision.

The checkObject subclass from the collision checker.

```
public int checkObject(Entity entity, boolean player) {
        
        int index = 999;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < gp.obj.length; i++) {
            
            if(gp.obj[i] != null) {
                
                // Get entity's solid area position
                entity.solidArea.x = entity.worldX + entity.solidArea.x;
                entity.solidArea.y = entity.worldY + entity.solidArea.y;
                // Get the object's solid area position
                gp.obj[i].solidArea.x = gp.obj[i].worldX + gp.obj[i].solidArea.x;
                gp.obj[i].solidArea.y = gp.obj[i].worldY + gp.obj[i].solidArea.y;
                
                switch (entity.direction) {
                case "up":
                    entity.solidArea.y -= entity.speed;
                    if(entity.solidArea.intersects(gp.obj[i].solidArea)) {
                        if(gp.obj[i].collision == true) {
                            entity.collisionOn = true;
                        }
                        if(player == true) {
                            index = i;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "down":
                    entity.solidArea.y += entity.speed;
                    if(entity.solidArea.intersects(gp.obj[i].solidArea)) {
                        if(gp.obj[i].collision == true) {
                            entity.collisionOn = true;
                        }
                        if(player == true) {
                            index = i;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "left":
                    entity.solidArea.x -= entity.speed;
                    if(entity.solidArea.intersects(gp.obj[i].solidArea)) {
                        if(gp.obj[i].collision == true) {
                            entity.collisionOn = true;
                        }
                        if(player == true) {
                            index = i;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "right":
                    entity.solidArea.x += entity.speed;
                    if(entity.solidArea.intersects(gp.obj[i].solidArea)) {
                        if(gp.obj[i].collision == true) {
                            entity.collisionOn = true;
                        }
                        if(player == true) {
                            index = i;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            entity.solidArea.x = entity.solidAreaDefaultX;
            entity.solidArea.y = entity.solidAreaDefaultY;
            gp.obj[i].solidArea.x = gp.obj[i].solidAreaDefaultX;
            gp.obj[i].solidArea.y = gp.obj[i].solidAreaDefaultY; 
            
        }
        
        return index;
        
    }
```

The player class where the error is coming from.

```
public void pickUpObject(int i) {

        if(i != 999) {
            String objectName = gp.obj[i].name;
            
            switch (objectName) {
            case "Paper":
                hasPaper++;
                gp.obj[i] = null;
                System.out.println("Paper: " + hasPaper);
                break;
            }
        }
        
        
    }
```

I've been at this for hours trying to understand the code/error.

I tried running the program without the gp.obj[i] = null code and it successfully ran without errors, other than that I did nothing more.